# Error in middleware-manifest.json (errno: -4094, code: 'UNKNOWN', syscall: 'readlink') in .Next file

Tags: next.js, middleware, readlink

My project was running fine when, with a small change in the code, npm run dev stopped working, and the terminal showed the following message:

```
[Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, readlink 'C:\\Users\\username\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Stuff\\web-project\\.next\\server\\middleware-manifest.json] 
{errno: -4094,  code: 'UNKNOWN',  
syscall: 'readlink',  
path: 'C:\\Users\\username\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Stuff\\web-project\\.next\\server\\middleware-manifest.json'}
```

I undid the small change (it was some text I was adding), but that didn't fix anything. I checked the file path and the permissions, and everything is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it, I asked You.com and it said to try and delete the .Next file, then rebuild for it to reappear. I deleted it and just ran with npm run dev, the .Next file appeared again and it no longer had the error.

Comment: I had a similar error message saying that a certain file within the .next directory was missing. Deleting the .next directory and restarting the server solved my problem as well